# Change boot order for Wubi

Tags: 10.04, wubi, boot, windows-vista

I've setup Ubuntu via Wubi recently for a friend and he came back with a complaint: On reboots the Windows partition is always selected by default, figured this was just a need to update Grub but realized that Wubi writes to the Windows Boot Manager and does not use Grub.

Though this is technically a "Windows" question I wasn't able to find a clear answer for this.

How to do I modify the boot/selection order for Operating systems (Mainly Ubuntu via Wubi) on the Windows Boot Manager?

Comment: What version of Windows is it?

Comment: This case it's Windows Vista

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wubi Guide on the Ubuntu wiki (manual uninstall section)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How%20do%20I%20manually%20uninstall%20Wubi?) gives some hints on how to edit the Windows Boot Manager boot order in Vista and XP.

In **Windows Vista** you can either use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) or modify the boot menu via `Control Panel (Classic View) > System > Advanced system settings`; then choose "Settings..." under Startup and Recovery.

In **Windows XP**, edit C:\boot.ini.

According to [this Wubi HowTo](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/wubi), the default OS can be changed in **Windows 7** by going to `Control Panel > Advanced System Settings`, and in the Default operating system drop-down selecting Ubuntu instead of Windows.

Comment: I'll gives these options a go - but this looks like what I'll need. Thanks!

Comment: Just some clarification in Vista it's `Control Panel (Classic View) > System > Advanced system settings` Then choose "Settings..." under Startup and Recovery

I wasn't able to test XP or Windows 7 but I'm accepting this answer as it did work well. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I updated the answer. Hopefully if someone else tries other Windows versions they'll comment whether it worked or not. I'm glad it worked for you on Vista!

Comment: You don't need to edit C:\boot.ini in XP. The same instuctions work on all versions of windows i.e. go to Startup & Recovery settings. WARNING: setting Ubuntu as the default and also the timeout below 10 can result in Windows not being able to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Click start and run msconfig(in Windows). Look for the Boot tab and change the order of the OS. I can't remember what it looks like its been a while, but its pretty self explanatory.

Good Luck and happy Ubuntuing!