# How do I change the OS name in the Boot menu - Windows bootloader?

Tags: 11.10, windows-7, wubi, bootloader

I have installed ubuntu 11.10 with Wubi (windows installer) and when i boot my computer it gives me the option of windows 7 home premium and Ubuntu. I want to change the name of Ubuntu to Windows 7 Recovery Module. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this belongs on Ask Ubuntu as the bootloader being used actually belongs to Windows. You'd need Windows technical advice to do this.

Comment: It bases the name of the OS on some kind of file within the OS doesn't it? if this is the case, then i should be able to change a file within Ubuntu and i would see the affect on my boot screen. Or am i just completely wrong on this?

Comment: No, that can't be right - the Windows bootloader (or even Windows for that matter) doesn't understand ext; the filesystem used by Linux; so it can't read anything in your Ubuntu installation. In XP it was a boot.ini, but in Win7 they've replaced it with bcd stuff afaik. But this is seriously offtopic for Ask Ubuntu now.

Comment: wubi uses the windows boot loader. You can change the default operating system but I can't find a way to rename them yet

Comment: actually, this question might be a dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760/change-boot-order-for-wubi (this question links to EasyBCD which can rename entries.. not free though!)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the text you want to change in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but be sure you read the instruction contained at the top of that file when you open it.
you have to open it as sudo/root, so you have to do something like:

in a terminal

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

or after ALT+F2 digit

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: Could doing so damage my system or make certain links not work?

Comment: -1: grub isn't used as primary bootloader for wubi (might be chainloaded later but that's irrelevant)

Comment: It's always a dangerous thing editing something that belong to your bootloader.

Comment: @caesium One of us does not have understood the question correctly, and i think i am not the one. If our friend say "Change OS name in Boot Menu" i think he can refer only to Grub.

Comment: @Micro, Windows also has a boot menu with names in it :) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi clearly shows the Windows Boot Loader

Answer (score 0):

Wubi uses the windows boot loader. There is a tutorial [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/5110-dual-boot-change-os-name-windows-boot-manager.html) that might work. But googling you need to find out about the windows boot loader